# How to make a batch to check status of one port on remote host using NSClient?

Tags: windows, batch-file, port, nagios

I saw that you can use netcat to scan for open ports but how can i scan a port in a batch file to send it to Nagios using NSclient?
for example i'm trying to check if port 7003 is open on a remote unix server from inside Windows Server, so the batch should check for the remote port on unix and send the feedback to Nagios so i can see  it on the monitoring site.
 The result of the current port search is:

```
nagios# /usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_nrpe2 -H 192.168.55.10 -c run_script -t 20
(UNKNOWN) [192.168.10.10] 7003 (?) open
```

This is what i have working now:

```
    @echo off
nc -v -n -z -w 3 192.168.10.10 7003
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto bueno 

:malo
echo TCServer Connectivity: Bad 
exit /b 2 
:bueno
echo TCServer: Connectivity Good
exit /b 0
:end
```

Thanks so much, i just had to understand the output of %errorlevel% with an `echo %errorlevel%` xD since i was thinking i get a 0 or 1 just by default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i have working now:

```
    @echo off
nc -v -n -z -w 3 192.168.10.10 7003
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto bueno 

:malo
echo TCServer Connectivity: Bad 
exit /b 2 
:bueno
echo TCServer: Connectivity Good
exit /b 0
:end
```

i just had to understand the output of %errorlevel% with an `echo %errorlevel%` xD since i was thinking i get a 0 or 1 just by default

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to use the [check_tcp](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_tcp) Nagios plugin that comes with the default plugin package?

Comment: Well i dont think i could use that command from within windows batch file, right now im doing this: `@echo off
nc -v -n -z -w 3 192.168.10.10 7003 | FIND "open" >new
IF %errorlevel%==1 ( echo Port 7003: All is Ok! ) ELSE (echo Connectivity: Not Ok!! )

@exit 0`  Now what i wish to know is how to get the exit 0 or Exit 2 output when they are Ok and Critical respectively  im calling this from nagios with `check_nrpe -H ip/host -c check_port` Good day people! xD

Comment: Oh, that is just a matter of executing `exit /b 0` or `exit /b 2`.

Comment: ok i think my problem here is with the FIND command, since i think its not searching within the output of the port search, yesterday i had no connectivity and still i was getting a green or OK flag on Nagios, any ideas for the FIND or the IF in here? Thanks!